# In Adobe Audition - can I see post-effect waveforms?

Tags: wave-editor, adobe-audition, user-interface

I'm using Audition to edit voices and adding compression, noise filters, etc. The waveforms in the multi-track session don't change when effects are applied - they are as they were imported.

I'd like to have the option of seeing the waveforms after they've been treated by the effects, so I have a visual sense of how the compression is working.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this in the multi-track section of Audition, but you can in the waveform editor if you turn on the preview editor in the view menu.

[image: Adobe Audition Preview Editor]

Not quite what you're after, but still a very useful feature if you need visual feedback of how an effect will change your audio before you click apply, and also a good teaching tool.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, and that is how it works in most audio software:

The amplitude wave is showing what has been loaded from disk. Any realtime effects are not shown.

Some software operate with the concept of destructive editing, meaning that the effect/operation is applied directly to the wavefile/memory object. This usually causes the wave display to update.

If you want to see the visual effect of realtime effect, you **need to render a temporary file and import that**.

Answer (score 0):

As Michael says, this is just the way it is in multi-track sessions, and it kind of makes sense that way: you're applying real-time effects after the fact, and those effects aren't altering the original waveform, so why should the waveform change.

Audition does, however, have a very good 'destructive' waveform editor. Double clicking on the waveform in the multi-track session will bring up the waveform editor; simply apply the effects in there and the waveform will change. The effects rack (window/effects rack) will enable effects chains to be saved and applied.

Be aware that any actions here will permanently change the file. If you don't want to lose the original file, click on the waveform in multi-track mode, then from the taskbar, clip/'Convert to Unique Copy'. This'll make a new version of the file, with the original file still available in the file list.

Comment: Ah thank you, this is helpful. The reason I want to do this is to be able to analyze a file I've, for example, added compression to and see how well it's working. Is there a good way to do this without converting and and copying the track?